# Can I Redirect from Child Action Method to the New Action Method and return their view instead of returning to the parent of that child?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

For Suppose I have an action method e.g **Pseudocode**

[Pseudo Code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smFW3.png)
Is this possible to redirect from child to another parent action mehtod and return their view instead of returning view to the parent of that child ?

Comment: please write your pseudo code in the question. You can use formatting to show it nicely (with indentation), by selecting the code in the question and hit Ctrl+k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return any response you like from any action.  Using your example:

```
public ActionResult Method()
{
    return ChildActionMethod();
}

public ActionResult ChildActionMethod()
{
    return RedirectToAction("SomeAction");
}
```

This would return the redirect result from `Method`, since it's returning whatever `ChildActionMethod` returns.

It's worth noting that if you do `return View();` within `ChildActionMethod` and don't specify the view, the framework will use the current request to determine which view to use.  That is, it will use the view for `Method` instead of `ChildActionMethod` by default.  You'd need to specify the view in this case.

In fact, `ChildActionMethod` doesn't even need to be a public "action method".  It can be any method which returns an `ActionResult`.  At this point you're dealing with just the basics of the C# language (methods, types, etc.), not so much the ASP.NET MVC Framework.